# Merge Matrix and Cell array of strings

Tags: matlab

I'm looking to export data to excel from Matlab in the form of

```
ColName     Value
=======     ======
Col1        Val1
Col2        Val2
```

I have my ColName in  `colheaders` which is a 1xM cell (of strings) and my values in `predRes` which is a 1xM Matrix (of double).

I've tried to combine the two into a single structure with the below code which doesn't work, giving me `??? Conversion to cell from double is not possible.`

```
out = cell(size(X,2),2);
out(:,1) = colheaders(2:end)';
out(:,2) = predRes';
```

functions like `mat2str` seem to merge the input into a single string, which isn't the right thing here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do.

If you want to save to Excel, you may mean this:

```
colheaders = {'aa','b','ccc'};
predRes = [1,2,3];
out = [colheaders', mat2cell(predRes',ones(3,1),1)];
s = xlswrite('tempdata.xls', out);
```

If you want to concatenate numbers to strings:

```
colheaders = {'aa','b','ccc'};
predRes = [1,2,3];
out = strcat(colheaders', num2str(predRes'))
```

Comment: I've updated my question to provide more clarity. For your suggestions, the first almost works, but gives a Nx1 result, and I need a Nx2 result. The second doesn't apply.

Comment: See my edit. I still can't guess what you need from your last edit. What I need to know is exactly the format of `out`, e.g., `{[1xM double], [1xM double]}`.

Comment: I think it would be {[String],[Double]}xM